# WooCommerce incredibly slow with Layered Nav/Taxonomy Filters

Tags: woocommerce, nav, layered

Having some major issues with Attribute/Taxonomy/Category filters.

First up, when adding WooCommerce layered nav widgets, 1 widget slows the entire page down 10 times, then adding another one leads to a 502 gateway. From there, I switched over to Ajax layered nav, same issue.

Now I am using MDTF Taxonomy filter widget and same problem minus the 502 gateway error. I have 22,000 products, a few hundred attributes>subattributes.

What is going on? Is there a way to speed this up? Am I missing a step?

Comment: Anyone know why layered navigation is incredibly slow? Even leads to 502?